# How to enable Worklight adapter to do remote JMS lookup

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have a Worklight 6.1 environment installed on a WAS ND application server profile.

My requirement is to connect to an external WebSphere MQ JMS queue manager using the Worklight JMS adapter component

I have created the necessary JMS definitions on the MQ queue manager

Connection Factory = mqWLCF
Queue Definition = TESTQ

I'm unable to get the adapter to work when installed to the Worklight environment on the WAS ND server

The connection code in the adapter xml file is -

```
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="jms:JMSConnectionPolicyType">

        <namingConnection url="tcp:/192.168.0.100:1417"
                initialContextFactory="com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory"/>

        <jmsConnection
                connectionFactory="mqWLCF"/>

     </connectionPolicy>
</connectivity>
```

What is the correct syntax in the adapter xml file ??

Answer (score 0):

```
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="jms:JMSConnectionPolicyType">     
        <namingConnection url="tcp:/127.0.0.1:61616"
                initialContextFactory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"
                user="admin"
                password="admin"/>


        <jmsConnection
                connectionFactory="ConnectionFactory"
                user="admin"
                password="admin"
                />
    </connectionPolicy>
    <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="10"/>
</connectivity>
```

You can find more information  regarding JMS adapter here:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_05_JMS_adapter_-_Communicating_with_JMS.pdf

Comment: I have gone through this Worklight JMS Adapter documentation but was unable to find the right values I need to provide for the URL and intialContextFactory parameter setting. I do not wish to use the 'file' option in the URL parameter as I would be connecting to external WebSphere MQ queue managers from the Worklight WAS ND server

Answer (score 0):

The naming connection URL and initial context factory must go hand in hand. For example, in the example you have provided, the ICF is `RefFSContextFactory` whereas the URL is a `tcp:/` URL (this corresponds to Active MQ - as Shmulik has answered). If you do not want to use file system, then you must mention what ICF do you want to use.

You can use LDAP for which the ICF will be `com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory`  and you must have the URL as `ldap://.....`

Similarly, for a lookup within WAS environment, you must have an ICF `com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory` and the corresponding URL.